# Perl Do...Until for User Input and Validation?

Tags: perl

Trying to Loop Until User provides a Valid Directory:

```
my $src;

#1. Get source directory
do {
print "Enter the Source Directory of .md Files (eg. /home/user/notes): \n";
chomp($src = <>);

#make sure directory exists
until (-e $src and -d $src);
```

I would like to display the following message:

`print "[ERROR] Invalid Directory Given...Please try again\n";`

When the `until` condition fails.

How can I do this elegently (without mountains of code)?

Sidenote: If there is a language that allows for better(more elegant) handling of this problem please share

Comment: For what it's worth, `-d $pathname` already implies `-e $pathname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a loop that looks like

1. Prompt.
2. Exit loop if input is valid.
3. Show error message.
4. Go to 1.

Code:

```
while (1) {
   print "Enter the Source Directory of .md Files (eg. /home/user/notes): ";
   $src = <>;
   die if !defined($src);

   chomp($src);
   last if -d $src;

   print "[ERROR] Invalid Directory Given...Please try again\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks, what does `die if !defined` do. And do you know if it is possible to allow for auto completion with tab while executing the script?

Comment: `<>` returns undefined when end-of-life is reached. Without that check, you could easily get into an infinite loop.

Comment: re: autocompletion, yes.  replace the print..chomp lines with `use IO::Prompter; $src = prompt 'Enter the Source Directory of .md Files (eg. /home/user/notes): ', -complete => 'dirnames'; die if !$src;`

Answer (score 3):

I like [`Term::UI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::UI) for creating user prompts, since it allows you to supply default values, validate the input, and other nifty features:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Term::ReadLine;
use Term::UI;

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('path');

$Term::UI::INVALID = 'Not a valid directory, please try again: ';

my $path = $term->get_reply(
    prompt  => 'Enter the Source Directory of .md Files',
    default => '/root',
    allow   => sub { return -d $_[0] }
);

say $path;
```

The default value is `/root`; to use the default, you can simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the prompt.

#### Output:

```
Enter the Source Directory of .md Files [/root]: /foo
Not a valid directory, please try again: [/root] /home
/home
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $src;

#1. Get source directory
while(1) {
    print "Enter the Source Directory of .md Files (eg. /home/user/notes): \n";
    chomp($src = <>);
    if (-e $src and -d $src) {
        last;
    } else {
        print "[ERROR] Invalid Directory Given...Please try again\n";
    }
}
```